# PHP regex for email in "From" parameter

Tags: php, regex

Take these four formats of the `from` parameter in an email's header:

`From: Jon Doe <jon.doe@a.validdomain.com>`

`From: "Jon Doe" <jon.doe@a.validdomain.com>`

`From: <jon.doe@a.validdomain.com>`

`From: jon.doe@a.validdomain.com`

Has anybody made a regular expression that can match the email address to use in preg_match for these? I have tried a few but the `<` and `>` are catching them out

Comment: are you looking to match just the email or the whole thing for each one?

Comment: just the email, without the '<' or '>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
^From:.*?<?(\S+@\S+?)>?\s*$  
This will match the whole thing in any of the 4 cases
```

If you are looking to match just email it has been asked again and again... just search for [regex email](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex%20email)

Email validation which will include any email with a + sign or . in the email as well as the basics would look like

```
\b[!#\$%&'\*\+\-/=\?\^_`{\|}~a-zA-Z0-9][!#\$%&'\*\+\-/=\?\^_`{\|}~a-zA-Z0-9\.]*[!#\$%&'\*\+\-/=\?\^_`{\|}~a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9\-][a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\b
This is what I use.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump(imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist($string));
```

Or even:

```
$headers = imap_rfc822_parse_headers("From: Jon Doe <jon.doe@a.validdomain.com>");
$from_email = $headers->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$headers->from[0]->host;
```

Comment: I should of said that I am using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap

Comment: So? What makes the difference? That function works perfectly well standalone, and probably catches more edge cases then any <25kbyte regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `([^<>\s]+)>?$`